# Alternative to CLUSTER without table lock

Tags: postgresql, locking, clustering

I'm facing performance degradation and increasing storage usage as a result of frequent new and updated records causing index and storage fragmentation.

VACUUM doesn't help much.

Unfortunetely CLUSTER isn't an option as it causes downtime and pg_repack isn't available for AWS RDS.

I'm looking for hacky alternatives to CLUSTER. One that seems to work fine in my local tests is:

```
begin;

create temp table tmp_target as select * from target;

delete from target;
insert into target select * from tmp_target order by field1 asc, field2 desc;

drop table tmp_target;

commit;
```

The ordering of `ctid` looks correct with:

```
select ctid, field1, field2 from target order by ctid;
```

The question is: does this look fine? Is it going to lock the `target` table for `SELECT` queries causing downtime in apps?
Is there a way to list the locks involved in the transaction?

Related to [Cluster command locking read only queries on replica](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166560/cluster-command-locking-read-only-queries-on-replica)

Comment: (Auto)vacuum is here to help. Is autovacuum configured and how ? You can also tune it per table (just like analyze) which might be useful for your most active tables. Please try those gentle methods first before. By the way, you could use TRUNCATE in your script, but would advise you against re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @KookieMonster please reread the first and second lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's just about table bloat, `VACUUM FULL` is the tool to do it. (`VACUUM` only shrinks the physical file if it can opportunistically truncate it at the end.) However, `VACUUM FULL` also takes an exclusive lock on the table, just like `CLUSTER`.
There are community tools to do the same **without exclusive lock**:

- [**pg_repack**](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack)
- [**pg_squeeze**](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze)

Unfortunately, most hosted services like [Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.Restriction) do not allow these additional modules, currently.

Related:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system/37032#37032)

Your current solution is no good, either way. You do the sort operation ***after*** deleting all rows (locking them), which will not shorten the downtime (the duration of the lock) for `SELECT` queries.

If you have **no concurrent write access** and **no depending objects**, this might be better:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_target AS TABLE target ORDER BY field1, field2 DESC;

TRUNCATE target;
INSERT INTO target TABLE tmp_target;

-- DROP TABLE tmp_target;  -- optional; dropped at end of session automatically

COMMIT;
```

1. Sort in the background *before* taking the lock.
   Strictly speaking, `INSERT` without `ORDER BY` is free to write rows in any physical order. Practically, though, it will normally copy the current physical order of the temp table with a plain `SELECT * FROM ...` (`TABLE ...` for short). May fail for *big* tables that involve multiple parallel workers. Then you may need `ORDER BY`.
2. For big tables, `TRUNCATE` is faster than `DELETE`. Be aware of some implications. Like: `TRUNCATE` does not work with FK constraints. [Read the manual for full coverage.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html)

You may want to drop existing indexes right before `TRUNCATE` and recreate after `INSERT` to make this faster.

Related:

- [Best way to populate a new column in a large table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52517/best-way-to-populate-a-new-column-in-a-large-table/52531#52531)
- [Why wouldn't VACUUM ANALYZE clear all dead tuples?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77560/why-wouldnt-vacuum-analyze-clear-all-dead-tuples/77570#77570)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: thanks @Erwin. It seems to work fine, the only thing necessary is to remove all FKs before and readd them after. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: another thing, how to lock a table only for writing? or isn't it necessary for this transaction?

Comment: this answer my first question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys (using `ccu` instead of `tc` in the where)

Comment: @vao thanks for pointing out! fixed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter my pleasure. You helped me a lot with your SO posts

Answer (score 2):

pg_repack [is available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.11x) on RDS now.

Comment: pg_repack uses a lot of storage and is very disk and CPU intensive, so I gave up using it

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: nothing :( still with fragmented data

Comment: Just to note, a `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER` is just as resource-intensive.  All solutions build a copy of the table (and indexes).  With `pg_repack` you pay some extra price for not being down during (most of) the time, but in my experience it's not that bad.